# Как добавить элемент с помощью Dnd на Layer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, konvajs

Как добавить с помощью перетаскивания переместить ,например картинку с изображение палки, на Layer. У меня есть div с картинками и я хочу перетащить ее на холст и чтоб она по окончанию перемещения стала элементом Rect на Layer.

```
<div><img src="./images/horizont.png" /></div>
        <Stage
          width={this.state.width}
          height={height}
          ref={(ref) => {
            this.stageRef = ref;
          }}
          onClick={this.handleClick}
        >
          <Provider store={window.store}>
            <Layer ref={(ref) => {
              this.lay = ref;
            }} scaleX={scale} scaleY={scale} y={20} x={20}>
              <Section
                section={root.sections[0]}
                x={root.frameSize}
                y={root.frameSize}

              />
              {/* <Sash
                width={root.width}
                height={root.height}
                size={root.frameSize}
              /> */}
              {/* <Metrics /> */}
            </Layer>
          </Provider>
        </Stage>
```